# SVG 4 Everybody freezes left and right click

Tags: javascript, svg, freeze, requestanimationframe

I'm using the `svg4everybody` and I don't understand why sometimes it **freezes** the **mouse interacions**.

The plugin is loaded in `many iframes` dynamically, but only some times it **freezes**.

If I hover on buttons and other clickable elements the cursor changes and if i press the **back button** the site goes back and the **freeze disappear**.

Looking in the [**source file**](https://github.com/jonathantneal/svg4everybody/blob/master/svg4everybody.js) I see that the `requestAnimationFrame` function is used:

```
function onframe() {
    var use;

    while ((use = uses[0])) {
        // some code
    }

    requestAnimationFrame(onframe);
}

if (IE9TO11) { // <-- edited in tests with if ( true || IE9TO11 )
    onframe();
}
```

It is possible that it's the `requestAnimationFrame` that make the **freeze**? Or someone has another better idea?

***NOTE:*** it freezes **only in IE11**. Tried in FF32 and Chrome 39 and works without problems

Comment: It checks the user agent and disables itself on FF and Chrome so saying it doesn't freeze there isn't really surprising.

Comment: @RobertLongson - You are right, but I replaced the if with `if ( true || IE9TO11)` for testing. I edited the code in the question.

Comment: I didn't like the fact that svg4everybody uses requestAnimationFrame. It's overkill. So I wrote a simple lightweight polyfill to make <use> with external references work in IE: https://github.com/Keyamoon/svgxuse